# Choose n most evenly spread points across point dataset in R

Tags: r, distance

Given a set of points, I am trying to select a subset of n points that are most evenly distributed across this set of points. In other words, I am trying to thin out the dataset while still evenly sampling across space.

So far, I have the following, but this approach likely won't do well with larger datasets. Maybe there is a more intelligent way to choose the subset of points in the first place...
The following code randomly chooses a subset of the points, and seeks to minimize the distance between the points within this subset and the points outside of this subset.

Suggestions appreciated!

```
evenSubset <- function(xy, n) {

    bestdist <- NA
    bestSet <- NA
    alldist <- as.matrix(dist(xy))
    diag(alldist) <- NA
    alldist[upper.tri(alldist)] <- NA
    for (i in 1:1000){
        subset <- sample(1:nrow(xy),n)
        subdists <- alldist[subset,-subset]
        distsum <- sum(subdists,na.rm=T)
        if (distsum < bestdist | is.na(bestdist)) {
            bestdist <- distsum
            bestSet <- subset
        }
    }
    return(xy[bestSet,])
}

xy2 <- evenSubset(xy=cbind(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000)), n=20)
plot(xy)
points(xy2,col='blue',cex=1.5,pch=20)
```

Comment: If you only care about the evenness of the spread of your subset S then you can do that independently of the remaining set of points. You want to minimise the empty-space nearest neighbour function (ie the distance from an arbitrary location to the nearest point in S). You might get this by constructing a voronoi tesselation and iteratively dropping the smallest area polygon. It will be much like the closest-pair dropping algorthm from the other question...

Answer (score 4):

Following @Spacedman's suggestion, I used voronoi tesselation to identify and drop those points that were closest to other points.

Here, the percentage of points to drop is given to the function. This appears to work quite well, except for the fact that it is slow with large datasets.

```
library(tripack)
voronoiFilter <- function(occ,drop) {
    n <- round(x=(nrow(occ) * drop),digits=0)
    subset <- occ
    dropped <- vector()
    for (i in 1:n) {
        v <- voronoi.mosaic(x=subset[,'Longitude'],y=subset[,'Latitude'],duplicate='error')
        info <- cells(v)
        areas <- unlist(lapply(info,function(x) x$area))
        smallest <- which(areas == min(areas,na.rm=TRUE))
        dropped <- c(dropped,which(paste(occ[,'Longitude'],occ[,'Latitude'],sep='_') == paste(subset[smallest,'Longitude'],subset[smallest,'Latitude'],sep='_')))
        subset <- subset[-smallest,]
    }
    return(occ[-dropped,])
}

xy <- cbind(rnorm(500),rnorm(500))
colnames(xy) <- c('Longitude','Latitude')
xy2 <- voronoiFilter(xy, drop=0.7)

plot(xy)
points(xy2,col='blue',cex=1.5,pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: But the areas of outermost Voronoi cells depend on the Voronoi diagram boundary, meaning they can be infinite, no? The outermost points are always selected however cramped they are..

Comment: For this method, that is, “popping the smallest Voronoi cells,” to work, **the Voronoi diagram has to be clipped into the _concave_ hull of the outermost points.** If you don’t, there’s no limit to the areas of the outermost Voronoi cells.