# For-loop produce NA into data frame with using seq_len or length in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to loop conditional distance calculation in data frame but problem occurs when determing loop sequence length. I've tried with seq_len and length but both ends up with df with NA-s. Original data is GPS coordinate data and I'm trying to get rid of some of GPS points that's close to each other.
I have following code for example:

```
form=function(n1,n2,m1,m2){
a=n1+n2
b=m1+m2
d=a-b
return(d)
}
n=c(3,3,4,3,4,2,4,8,4,5,3)
m=c(3,2,1,3,4,5,6,8,3,4,2)
df=data.frame(n,m)

df1=df 
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df1))){##same with 1:length(df1$n)
dist=form(df1$n[i], df1$m[i], df1$n, df1$m)
df1$distance<-dist
df1<-(df1[with(df1, !(distance >=1 & distance <=2)), ])
}
```

Which gives:

```
df1
n  m distance
NA   NA NA       NA
NA.1 NA NA       NA
NA.2 NA NA       NA
```

When using cut-and-dry method then there are 4 iterations and loop works:

```
for (i in 1:4)){
dist=form(df1$n[i], df1$m[i], df1$n, df1$m)
df1$distance<-dist
df1<-(df1[with(df1, !(distance >=1 & distance <=2)), ])
}
```

Which gives:

```
df1
n m distance
7  4 6       -1
8  8 8       -7
10 5 4        0
```

What I'm doing wrong determing loop sequence length?
Thanks.

Comment: One way around is to run my loop 2 times. First time it doesn't give numbers into df but I'll get length for loop and second run will provide me data into table. It is very unefficient way to do that and with bigger data quite annoying but works for me:)

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the length of the loop is not the real reason for the NA values. The underlying problem is that you have the loop over-writing its own input, so that the number of rows doesn't stay the same as the loop proceeds. I have a hard time seeing what you're trying to do, so it's difficult to give you a good solution.

If you try this it won't return any NAs, but I'm not sure if it's the output you're looking for.

```
df1=df

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    dist <- form(df$n[i], df$m[i], df$n, df$m)
    df$distance <- dist
    df1 <- (df[with(df, !(distance >=1 & distance <=2)), ])
}
df1
#    n m distance
# 1  3 3       -1
# 2  3 2        0
# 3  4 1        0
# 4  3 3       -1
# 5  4 4       -3
# 6  2 5       -2
# 7  4 6       -5
# 8  8 8      -11
# 9  4 3       -2
# 10 5 4       -4
# 11 3 2        0
```

Comment: On real data (coordinates) I have many GPS points in small area and I'll try to get rid of most of them except one that's determined by condition. Goal is to put points on map but I don't want so many of them to be presented.

Comment: @marsilt: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228946/choose-n-most-evenly-spread-points-across-point-dataset-in-r) could be of help then?

Comment: This is good solution but I would prefer that location hot spots would remain presented while this voronei tesselation doesn't take account point density but tries to spread them as evenly as possible. In animal behaviour that gives biased point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your 'form' function does, but this may help u:

```
n=c(3,3,4,3,4,2,4,8,4,5,3)
m=c(3,2,1,3,4,5,6,8,3,4,2)

df=data.frame(n,m)

df1=df 
i=1
while(i<nrow(df1)){##same with 1:length(df1$n)
  dist=form(df1$n[i], df1$m[i], df1$n, df1$m)
  df1$distance<-dist
  df1<-(df1[with(df1, !(distance >=1 & distance <=2)), ])
  i =i+1
}
```

Result:

```
   n m distance
5  4 4        0
7  4 6       -2
8  8 8       -8
10 5 4       -1
```

Comment: On real data (coordinates) I have many GPS points in small area and I'll try to get rid of most of them except one that's determined by condition. Goal is to put points on map but I don't want so many of them to be presented.

Answer (score -1):

I not know why that outcome is produced, because `seq_len(nrow(df1))` is same as `1:11` (and that work!).

But i think you make basic mistake in for-loop. In each step, `df1$distance` is replaced. At end `df1$distance` is filled with the distance calulation between the 11th observation and all observations (including itself).

I guess you want create sort of distance maxtrix and pick a certain values from that.

A distance matrix like that can be made by `outer`-function:

```
 m <- outer(df$n + df$m, df$n + df$m, '-')
```

Result:

```
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    0    1    1    0   -2   -1   -4  -10   -1    -3     1
 [2,]   -1    0    0   -1   -3   -2   -5  -11   -2    -4     0
 [3,]   -1    0    0   -1   -3   -2   -5  -11   -2    -4     0
 [4,]    0    1    1    0   -2   -1   -4  -10   -1    -3     1
 [5,]    2    3    3    2    0    1   -2   -8    1    -1     3
 [6,]    1    2    2    1   -1    0   -3   -9    0    -2     2
 [7,]    4    5    5    4    2    3    0   -6    3     1     5
 [8,]   10   11   11   10    8    9    6    0    9     7    11
 [9,]    1    2    2    1   -1    0   -3   -9    0    -2     2
[10,]    3    4    4    3    1    2   -1   -7    2     0     4
[11,]   -1    0    0   -1   -3   -2   -5  -11   -2    -4     0
```

Now you can extract different forms of distances from that:

```
# average distance
rowMeans(m)
# distance sum
rowSums(m)
```

Comment: Original data is GPS coordinates and I want to get rid of some of the coordinates that are close to each other. Yes, I thought about distance matrix but I'd like to use coordinate points insted of distance between them. Distance would be parameter to exclude some points.

Comment: One way around is to run my loop 2 times. First time it doesn't give numbers into df but I'll get length for loop and second run will provide me data into table. It is very unefficient way to do that and with bigger data quite annoying but works for me:)